# Shuffle an array multiple times in Java

Tags: java, arrays

So i have this simple program, which creates an array of 16 numbers, shuffles them, and then counts the cycles in the array.

```java
import java.util.*;
public class ShuffleArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 16;
        Integer[] intArray = new Integer[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            intArray[i] = i;
        }
        List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(intArray);
        Collections.shuffle(intList);
        intList.toArray(intArray);
        System.out.println("The array: " + Arrays.toString(intArray));
        System.out.println("Number of cycles: " + countCycles(intArray));
    }

    public static int countCycles(Integer[] intArray) {
        int position = 0;
        int cycles = 0;
        int temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
            if (intArray[i] != -1) {
                position = i;
                while (intArray[position] != -1) {
                    temp = intArray[position];
                    intArray[position] = -1;
                    position = temp;
                }
                cycles = cycles + 1;
            }
        }
        return cycles;
    }
}
```

Now I need to add a method, which makes the program run 10.000.000 and stores the number of cycles in an array, such if there are 1.000 cycles of 1, 25.000 cycles of 2, etc.

How do I create this in an easy way?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean by cycle.  Is it how many times a number ends up in the same spot over all the shuffles?

Comment: It is a sorting cycle - so if the number 10 is stored in the first spot, the number 5 is on spot 10, and number 0 is in spot 5 - then that is 1 cycle. Then you move on to the 2nd spot in the array and check that number.

Comment: @WJS It's related to solving the 100 prisoners problem, among other discussions in mathematics. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/100_prisoners_problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this using a map. Note that since you are destroying your array each time you need to make a copy before you pass it to the method (or in the method if you prefer).  Also, the List is backed up by the array.  So when the List is shuffled, so is the array.

The map initializes to 1 for each value if it doesn't exist.  Otherwise it adds 1 to the previous value, instituting a count.

```
List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(intArray);
Map<Integer, Integer> cycles = new TreeMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++) {
    Collections.shuffle(intList);
    int count = countCycles(Arrays.copyOf(intArray, intArray.length));
    cycles.compute(count, (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1);
}
cycles.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints something like

```
1=624904
2=2074067
3=2945228
4=2417326
5=1294539
6=482924
7=130392
8=26230
9=3895
10=455
11=39
12=1
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot <3